# Numpy: Vectorization in the context of a 1:many operation

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have the following functions defined only to create the function topology the question is about:

```
def foo(x,y):
  return np.asarray([x for i in range(y)])

bar = lambda x: foo(x,10)
barv = np.vectorize(bar)

z = np.asarray([1, 2, 3])
```

And the following routine:

```
for i in range(z.shape[0]):
  rng = np.arange(z[i],100)
  # res = barv(rng)
  res = np.asarray(list(map(bar,rng)))
```

The above routine works.  However, if I uncomment and run the vectorized version, i.e.:

```
for i in range(z.shape[0]):
  rng = np.arange(z[i],100)
  res = barv(rng)
```

The code fails with the follwing error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-14-660195661e55>", line 3, in <module>
    res = barv(rng)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2091, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2170, in _vectorize_call
    res = array(outputs, copy=False, subok=True, dtype=otypes[0])
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

The error makes sense.  However, there must be some way to do a vectorized 1:many operation in numpy?

Answer (score 0):

`vectorize` is meant to be used with `scalar` functions, ones that take scalar inputs, and return scalar output.

```
In [729]: foo(z,10)                                                                              
Out[729]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
In [730]: bar(z)                                                                                 
Out[730]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

Your `bar` is returns a 2d array if given a 1d input.  Or a 1d array if given a scalar input

```
In [734]: bar(4)                                                                                 
Out[734]: array([4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4])
```

We can tell `vectorize` to expect an `object` return,

```
In [735]: barv = np.vectorize(bar, otypes=[object])                                              
In [736]: barv(4)                                                                                
Out[736]: array([4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], dtype=object)
In [737]: barv(z)                                                                                
Out[737]: 
array([array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]),
       array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]),
       array([3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3])], dtype=object)
```

which can be turned into a 2d array with:

```
In [738]: np.stack(_)                                                                            
Out[738]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]])
```

`vectorize` also has a signature parameter, that might help in this case.  But in my experience it's even slower.

But we don't need `vectorize` here - a simple list comprehension is just as good, probably better:

```
In [739]: np.stack([bar(i) for i in z])                                                          
Out[739]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]])
```

`vectorize` makes 'broadcasting' with several input arrays easier, but it does not improve speed.  See if you can figure out what `vectorize` is doing here with `foo`:

```
In [743]: f = np.vectorize(foo, otypes=[object])                                                 
In [744]: f(np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([2,3,4]))                                                
Out[744]: array([array([1, 1]), array([2, 2, 2]), array([3, 3, 3, 3])], dtype=object)
In [745]: f(np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([[2],[3]]))                                              
Out[745]: 
array([[array([1, 1]), array([2, 2]), array([3, 3])],
       [array([1, 1, 1]), array([2, 2, 2]), array([3, 3, 3])]],
      dtype=object)
```

### edit

Correct `numpy` vectorization:

```
In [762]: np.repeat(z[:,None],10,1)                                                              
Out[762]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]])
```

Some time comparisons:

```
In [766]: timeit np.stack(barv(z))                                                               
60 µs ± 1.35 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [767]: timeit np.stack([bar(i) for i in z])                                                   
39.6 µs ± 132 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [768]: timeit np.repeat(z[:,None],10,1)                                                       
4.12 µs ± 14.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Your `foo` already works with an array input.  There was no need for a `np.vectorize` wrapper.

```
In [783]: foo(z,10).T                                                                            
Out[783]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]])
In [784]: timeit foo(z,10).T                                                                     
10.8 µs ± 364 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: I realize that.  However, in a compiled language I would be indifferent to this issue.  Maps can be 1:1, 1:many, many:1; they can be surjective, injective or bijective.  Numpy's vectorization potentially accesses C/C++ code with `#pragma omp simd` loops that provide a 10x speed-up, nested in a GEMM loop that gets another 1000x in addition to removing interpreted language memory shuffling overhead in the cache (which induces 64 cycles of no-op for every shuffle miss).  There must be some syntactical doo-hickey that python has defined to render itself non-useless for a set of 1:n ops

Comment: `np.vectorize` does not compile anything.  It runs `bar` once for each element of input array.  Your `foo` is a Python function.  True `vectorization` in `numpy` means rewriting the code to make full use of compiled `numpy` functionality.  Your `foo` could be rewritten a `np.repeat(x[:,None], y, 1)` (see my edits)